# xcode warning "-method 'imagePath' not found (return type defaults to 'id' "

Tags: iphone, class, methods, properties, warnings

Hi I have this weird warning in my iphone app:

```
-method 'imagePath' not found (return type defaults to 'id'
```

It's giving me this warning on the following line:

```
UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageNamed:[_occasion imagePath]];
```

Here is my Occasion class header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Occasion : NSObject {

NSString *_title;
NSDate *_date;
NSString *_imagePath;    
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imagePath;

+ (id)occasionWithTitle:(NSString *)title
         date:(NSDate *)date
           imagePath:(NSString *)imagePath;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
         date:(NSDate *)date
           imagePath:(NSString *)imagePath;
@end
```

The weird thing is I'm getting this warning only on the (imagePath property of Occasion, while the other 2 properties are working fine namely:

```
[_occasion date]
```

and

```
[_occasion title]
```

I dunno why is it complaining the method is not found while it is a property and it does exist.

Comment: Did you @synthesize imagePath in Occasion.m ?

Comment: Try changing its name (I don't think that is the problem though).

Comment: viggo24  yes imagePath is synthesized in Occasion.m

Comment: EmptyStack I have lots of files and changing the name would take some time. I don't think that's the problem either. Note that other properties like date and title are not giving an error whatsoever. Also I'm referencing [_occasion imagePath] in another file and no warnings at all. Really weird. Could it be a bug in the compiler? Should I ignore the warning for the time being?

Comment: Actually there is another warning on the same line too. It appears sometimes only and it says: `No '-imagePath' method found`. I know, not too informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I imported the Occasion.h file in MyFile.m since I was using the forward declearation @class Occasion.h only in MyFile.h.
It's still weird though
cuz in AnotherFile.h only @class Occasion.h was enough without the import in the AnotherFile.m